# Nono dígito opcional usando Jquery Mask Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask-plugin

Como posso fazer com que a formatação do Jquery Mask Plugin se adeque automaticamente à quantidade de dígitos? para telefones com 8 dígitos e/ou com 9 (opcional), está assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#phone').mask('(00) 00000-0000');
});
```

Saída: (71) 9999-9999 (8 dígitos)

Saída correta: (71) 8888-8888

E quando for para 9:

Saída: (71) 98888-8888

Comment: Achei a solução na página do plugin para este problema específico: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Mas a duplicata não é do mesmo plugin.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Como lá a pergunta pede Mask Plugin, acho que caberia você postar uma resposta lá. Assim quem achar qualquer uma das duas perguntas, vai ser apontado pra mesma solução. E avise a gente, pq além de estar ajudando os outros, ganha uns pontinhos.